# Enable output caching for default ASPX page in a Sitecore-enabled ASP.NET website?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, sitecore, outputcache

I am enabling output caching in my Sitecore-enabled ASP.NET site by putting this in my default.aspx (which lives outside the CMS):

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="300" VaryByParam="None" %>
```

and in my Web.config:

```
<setting name="DisableBrowserCaching" value="false" />
```

This works when I hit my page directly, as in http://[website]/default.aspx, but not when I browse to the root site http://[website]/.  In this case it always returns a 200 response, rather than 304 (not modified) on repeat requests.

I have tried the same in a website that does not use Sitecore, and caching works in all instances under IIS 7 and with Sitecore 6.4.1.

How do I enable output caching for default (extensionless) ASP.NET pages in a Sitecore-enabled site?

**Update:**
Seems to work on my local machine (this issue was in our QA environment), only difference I can see is that I have IIS 7.5 rather than 7.0, but same web.config and Sitecore instance.

Also, I have created another test page (http://[website]/**Test/default.aspx**) which exhibits the same behavior, so it is not only the root that is affected.

**Update 2:**
Bad news - Sitecore have confirmed that Output Caching is [not officially supported](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%206/ReleaseNotes/KnownIssues%20Recommended/ASP%20NET%20Output%20Caching.aspx):

"Sitecore CMS was not designed to work with enabled User-mode or Kernel-mode output caching in IIS and does not support its usage."

This doesn't explain why it *sometimes* works for specific URLs and environments, and I would still appreciate a workaround.

Comment: re: "Update" (the first one) Are your behavioral differences perhaps due to integrated vs classic mode app pools?

Comment: Paul - both app pools are v4.0 Integrated

Answer (score 1):

I did quick test and it looks like setting **DisableBrowserCaching** to false and adding **OutputCache** directive to the aspx layout file works fine.

Right, the response code is **200 OK**, but the page is taken from the cache of the browser (not from the server). Response code **304** would mean that there was a call to the server and the server answered that nothing was changed.

Could you double check whether the code of the page is executed on the server side?

Comment: I am seeing a GET request in Fiddler with a 200 response for the root site, and I can see that a full response is being returned from the server every time.  Not possible to attach to the code in our QA environment.  I'll update the question to reflect my findings...

Answer (score -1):

If using sitecore, you would need to put the directive into each of your layout (.aspx) files so that the presentation settings are always one of these layouts.

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="300" VaryByParam="None" %>
```

If your homepage was using a different layout minus the directive, it may explain the behavour.

That aside, it's likely that you will be better off using Sitecore's in built caching methods.

Comment: Thanks, but my default.aspx is just a vanilla ASP.NET page that lives outside the CMS, so doesn't use any Sitecore layout files.  It's just the fact that the Sitecore modules are installed in IIS that is causing the issue (I think).

Comment: Ahhh right. In which case, you may have a fight on your hands getting Sitecore to let go of the root url. You can configure "ignored url prefixes" in sitecore web.config which will tell Sitecore to ignore urls beginning with a known prefix, but not the other way around, you couldn't add "/" to the prefix list without Sitecore ignoring everything everywhere...

Answer (score -2):

You need to enable caching on your public site in the web.config:

```
<Sites>
  <site name="website" cacheHtml="true" ... />
```

Normally ouput caching works on component level and is configured in Sitecore on the presentation.

Comment: I already have that setting, full config: <site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />